# How to perform NOT CONTAINS in CASSANDRA?

Tags: cassandra

I am working on creating cassandra tables to support various queries my application makes. So far it's great, except I'm having a problem with one particular case:

We have a tinder-like interface where a user can vote "up" or "down" on a photo. I would like to dynamically serve the top 5 photos per query, sorted according to a custom "score", which excludes photos that a user has already voted on.

The pool of photos and the votes per photo are potentially > 10,000 each.

I was thinking of creating a table with a column of "votes: set" containing user ids, but it doesn't help because you can't query by NOT CONTAINS.

Is there a way to perform this query efficiently in Cassandra?

Comment: Any luck with your search for how to do "NOT CONTAINS" in CQL? Or any good work around?

Comment: Not really. I ended up splitting the work into smaller pieces by segmenting by time, then querying for N+5 items in each time period and doing the exclusion in the application code.